# Product details page get product custom attribute and apply custom css

Tags: magento2, module, css

I have create a custom attribute for a product. The attribute name is "hide"
When product load at product detail page, if this product custom attribute is "hide", it will apply a css to hide certain class label in the product details page.

If I want to build this as a custom module, what is the proper way to do it?
anyone can give me samples or reference that I can follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear from your question where the html element is on the product page that you wish to show/hide. If it is in the `details.phtml` template you can extend this in your module or theme at

```
Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\details.phtml
```

Check for your custom attribute and apply the css class name to the html element you want to hide/show:

```
<?php

$productView=$block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View');
$product=$productView->getProduct();

?>

<div class="<?= ($product->getCustomAttributeName()==='hide' ? 'hide':'') ?>"</div>
```

You will find many examples on how to create custom modules for Magento 2. One useful tool is the [Mage2Gen](https://mage2gen.com/) module creator which lets you quickly build the files you need for your module template.